# How to enable SSL in Alfresco SharePoint Protocol

Tags: ssl, sharepoint, https, ms-office, alfresco

For editing Microsoft Office Documents  in alfresco community edition 5.2, I installed the amp MS Office SharePoint Protocol
the edit online option works fine in http but not in htpps

I followed this steps with no hope  :(

1. create tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/vti-custom-context.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://
www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
 <beans>
  <bean id="vtiServerConnector" class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
    <property name="port">
       <value>${vti.server.port}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="headerBufferSize">
       <value>32768</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime">
       <value>30000</value>
    </property>
    <property name="keystore">
       <value>${vti.server.ssl.keystore}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="keyPassword">
       <value>${vti.server.ssl.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
       <value>${vti.server.ssl.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="keystoreType">
       <value>JCEKS</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

2. add the required attributes to alfresco-global.properties

```html
vti.server.port=7070
vti.server.protocol=https
vti.server.ssl.keystore=/opt/alfresco/alf_data/keystore/ssl.keystore
vti.server.ssl.password=kT9X6oe68t
vti.server.url.path.prefix=/alfresco
vti.server.external.host=localhost
vti.server.external.port=7070
vti.server.external.protocol=https
vti.server.external.contextPath=/alfresco
```

3. restart alfresco service

Comment: That looks broadly correct, what isn't working for you? Did you add your SSL key and certificate to the keystore mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I did! and i checked that the server is running correctly by opening this URL : https://<my-ip-server>:7070/alfresco

Comment: OK, so what's the problem then? What isn't working? What error do you get? etc

Comment: The edit on ligne feature not working for me , and i checked the log file with no vti problem !!

Comment: Define "not working". Button doesn't show up? Office doesn't open? Office opens but gives an error? Opens read only? Office opens, steals your life savings then crashes? Other?

Comment: Office doesn't open

Comment: Are you using a supported version of Office, with the relevant plugin installed?